# emacs gui from the terminal

Tags: emacs, bashrc

I have in my `~/.bashrc` an alias setup so emacs will open in the terminal.  How can I open the gui without commenting out the alias, closing down the terminal, re-opening the terminal, and then doing emacs `return`?

I need to open the GUI every now and then but not too often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround an alias, use the full path:

```
/usr/bin/emacs
```

or enclose the command in quotes:

```
'emacs'
```

or escape any character:

```
\emacs
```

You can also remove aliases temporarily using `unalias`.